# How to retrieve a certain view in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm currently listening and watching to iPad / iPhone application development and working assignments/demo. So I see one thing displayed in the video I'm watching to this image(image 1) :

[image]

But in my Xcode I see this image(without the thingies that red arrow from the previous image points to) :

[image]

How do I get these the cube and the circle from the image one into my code? It might be some MAC thing or Xcode thing. I'm using both as of past 5 days, first time ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the scene (the view controller) and it will change.

EDIT:

I don't know why that isn't working for you, but it doesn't really matter. The icons are only there as shortcuts for making connections. If you click the round grey arrow near the bottom of your screen, it will bring up a sidebar that has equivalent icons and many others.

Comment: I if this is what you had in mind? http://i40.tinypic.com/2ik4l8o.png just clicking on it made it blue ..

Comment: On my version of xcode it changes when you select it. I'll update my answer.